# PHP/Ajax not returning proper error and not recognizing POST vars?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Everytime it's returning **Oops!** All inputs must be entered.  Double-check the form.

It should be returning the next error in line, but I guess it's not recognizing my POST variables?  Why is this?

Code below:

PHP Script:

```
if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    switch($_POST['action']) {

        case 'register':

        $email_adress = @$_POST['register_email_address'];
        $password = hash('sha512', @$_POST['register_password']);
        $confirm_password = hash('sha512', @$_POST['register_confirm_password']);
        $safe_pin = @$_POST['register_safe_pin'];

            if(isset($email_address, $password, $confirm_password, $safe_pin)) {

                if(filter_var($email_address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

                    if($password == $confirm_password) {

                        if(strlen($safe_pin) == 4 && is_numeric($safe_pin)) {

                            if(strlen($_POST['register_password']) >= 6 && strlen($_POST['register_confirm_password']) >= 6) {

                                $insert_user = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users`
                                (`email_address`, `password`, `safe_pin`, `time_registered`, `activated`, `balance`, `last_login, `ip_address`, `last_ip_address`)
                                VALUES (:email_address, :password, :safe_pin, :time_registered, :activated, :balance, :last_login, :ip_address, :last_ip_address)");

                                    $insert_user->execute(array(

                                        ':email_address'        => $email_address,
                                        ':password'             => $password,
                                        ':safe_pin'             => $safe_pin,
                                        ':time_registered'      => time(),
                                        ':activated'            => 0,
                                        ':balance'              => 0,
                                        ':last_login'           => 0,
                                        ':ip_address'           => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                                        ':last_ip_address'      => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

                                    ));

                            }

                            else { echo json_encode(array('result'  => '<strong>Oops!</strong> Your password must be a minimum of 6-characters.')); }
                        }
                            else { echo json_encode(array('result'  => '<strong>Oops!</strong> Your safe-pin must be a 4-character numeric code.')); }
                    }
                            else { echo json_encode(array('result'  => '<strong>Oops!</strong> Your confirmation password must match identically to your password.')); }
                }
                            else { echo json_encode(array('result'  => '<strong>Oops!</strong> Your e-mail address must be valid.  Make sure it\'s typed properly. <br />')); }
            }
                            else { echo json_encode(array('result'  => '<strong>Oops!</strong> All inputs must be entered.  Double-check the form. <br />')); }

        break;
   }
}
```

jQuery/Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#sign_up").on('click', function() {
    $.post('./includes/ajax.php', { action: 'register' } , function(result) {
      var result = JSON.parse(result);
        console.log(result.result);
        $("#register_result").append(result.result);
    });
  });
$("#register_form").submit(function() {
  return false;
});

$(".alert").hide();
$("#sign_up").on('click', function() { $(".alert").show(); });
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="register_form">
              <form class="bs-example form-horizontal" id="register_form" method="POST" action="./includes/ajax.php">
                <fieldset>
                  <legend>Create a Wallet</legend>
                      <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
             <span id="register_result"></span>
            </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Your E-mail Address." name="register_email_address">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Your 6-character password." name="register_password">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Confirm</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Your 6-character password." name="register_confirm_password">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Safe-Pin</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Your 4-digit safe-pin." name="register_safe_pin">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="sign_up">Sign Up</button> 
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: Maybe `<button type="submit"` to `<button type="button"` ? Put header in JSON as `header('Content-Type: application/json')`? Not sure,..

Comment: Just so you're aware, you're allowing the user to leave the password field empty. At the `isset` checks before hashing occurs, also change it to `empty`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing your form to your register script. You must [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the contents of the form and send the post request

```
$("#sign_up").on('click', function() {
    $.post('./includes/ajax.php', $('#register_form').serialize() + '&action=register' , function(result) {
        var result = JSON.parse(result);
        console.log(result.result);
        $("#register_result").append(result.result);
    });
});
```

Comment: The string concatenation operator in JavaScript is `+` not `.`, but otherwise this sounds correct to me.

Comment: Woops, thanks for the correction, Anthony. Too much Perl, I guess!

Answer (score 0):

I updated now my whole answer... because you have more then 1 error in your code.

The first think what you have to do is, to buy an IDE (Software) for highlighting error's. That can make your life so easy.

Show your code so often as you can, read this up and down, again and again, comment out some lines of code to test whats wrong... and so on!

I think this code is now absolutely free of errors and clear.

What I changed:

1. `$email_adress` to `$email_address`
2. `if (strlen($_POST['register_password']) >= 6 &&   strlen($_POST['register_confirm_password']) >= 6) {...`

   to

   `if (strlen($_POST['register_password']) > 5 && strlen($_POST['register_confirm_password']) > 5) {...`
3. `:password` to `:pwd` I changed because that can be a reserved word and it is not so obvious (change it as you like)

and

```
...`last_login, `ip_address`,...
```

to (forget backtick)

```
...`last_login`, `ip_address`,...
```

and the whole code:

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {

    switch($_POST['action']) {

    case 'register':

        $email_address      = @$_POST['register_email_address'];
        $password           = hash('sha512', @$_POST['register_password']);
        $confirm_password   = hash('sha512', @$_POST['register_confirm_password']);
        $safe_pin           = @$_POST['register_safe_pin'];

        if (isset($email_address, $password, $confirm_password, $safe_pin)) {

            if (filter_var($email_address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

                if ($password == $confirm_password) {

                    if (strlen($safe_pin) == 4 && is_numeric($safe_pin)) {

                        if (strlen($_POST['register_password']) > 5 && strlen($_POST['register_confirm_password']) > 5) {

                            $insert_user = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`email_address`, `pwd`, `safe_pin`, `time_registered`, `activated`, `balance`, `last_login`, `ip_address`, `last_ip_address`)
                                                         VALUES (:email_address, :pwd, :safe_pin, :time_registered, :activated, :balance, :last_login, :ip_address, :last_ip_address)");

                            $insert_user->execute(array(

                                ':email_address'        => $email_address,
                                ':pwd'                  => $password,
                                ':safe_pin'             => $safe_pin,
                                ':time_registered'      => time(),
                                ':activated'            => 0,
                                ':balance'              => 0,
                                ':last_login'           => 0,
                                ':ip_address'           => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                                ':last_ip_address'      => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

                            ));

                        }

                        else { echo json_encode(array('result'  => '<strong>Oops!</strong> Your password must be a minimum of 6-characters.')); }
                    }
                    else { echo json_encode(array('result'  => '<strong>Oops!</strong> Your safe-pin must be a 4-character numeric code.')); }
                }
                else { echo json_encode(array('result'  => '<strong>Oops!</strong> Your confirmation password must match identically to your password.')); }
            }
            else { echo json_encode(array('result'  => '<strong>Oops!</strong> Your e-mail address must be valid.  Make sure it\'s typed properly. <br />')); }
        }
        else { echo json_encode(array('result'  => '<strong>Oops!</strong> All inputs must be entered.  Double-check the form. <br />')); }

        break;
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I put the backtick but that didn't solve anything.  It should be saying my e-amil must be valid, but it can't make it past the first if statement.

Comment: yeah...your variable is different: `$email_adress` and the other one is: `$email_address`... :-)

Comment: show now the updated version and tell me what happens...good luck